# Transforming Series with 2nd Moment Nonstationarity

Tags: time-series, econometrics, stationarity, univariate

I am trying to induce stationarity in this series.  I have graphed a range-mean plot to detect 1st and 2nd moment nonstationarity.  Can anyone suggest a transformation that will remedy the 2nd moment nonstationarity?  My professor covered 3 Box-Cox transformations, but they applied to linear range-mean plots.

[image: Range Mean Plot]

[image]

Comment: We can't see the series. What is this plot supposed to tell you about nonstationarity? Why do you think Box-Cox transformations could yield stationarity? What does CPI mean? (This is an interdisciplinary and international forum; I can guess, but we should not have to.)

Comment: The range mean plot can help detect 1st and 2nd moment nonstationarity.  The range is used as an alternative to the variance.  Since the variance and mean are both changing throughout the series (displayed on the scatter plot) then we suspect 1st and 2nd moment nonstationarity.  I was using Box-Cox transformation to attempt to fix the 2nd moment nonstationarity.  The CPI is the consumer price index. I apologize for not mentioning that.

Comment: I see your plot as implying that range doesn't really depend on the mean. As I distrust ranges any way -- and fail to see why you can't show variances if they are the real quantities of interest -- the graph seems underwhelming to me. How many values is each point based on, any way? Why not show us a plot of the original time series? I still fail to see why Box-Cox is pertinent.

Comment: You don't really have enough data to conclude there is second order nonstationarity from this plot, for several reasons. First, the range is an unstable surrogate for the variance. Second, your data surely have strong serial correlation.  Third, there are few points within each visible segment of the plot, casting doubt on any trends.  Although you can cure some of these problems by using robust statistics (choose median and IQR), overall the plot is unreadable due to these deficiencies and because we have no idea what subset of the data each individual point corresponds to!

Comment: I added the original time series to the question.  What is another method for detecting 2nd moment nonstationarity?  If it is detected, how should it be handled?  I was instructed to utilize Box-Cox transformations.

Comment: From your mean-range plot and the series plot it seems that (range, mean) pairs are for individual years. Is the index seasonally adjusted? Either way, assessing variability within years is one choice among several.

Comment: The pairs are for individual months from January 1980 to December 2013.  The series consists of raw data, prior to seasonal adjustment.

Comment: So, "range" is quantifying amplitude of seasonality.

Comment: So should I not worry about transforming the series, and start with seasonal differencing?

Comment: I wouldn't transform anything; the data are what they are, unless you want to make seasonal adjustments.

Comment: Okay.  I have questions regarding seasonal adjustments but will save those for another thread.  @NickCox Thank you for your help and working through this with me.  I have a great deal to learn.